# wash_out "No route matches _action"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wash-out

I am trying to get wash_out working in a rails 4 application but no dice.

```
# tains_controller.rb 
class TainsController  < ActionController::Base
  include WashOut::SOAP

  soap_action :get_balance,
    :to     => :balance,
    :args   => {
      :userName         => :string,
      :operatorId       => :string,
      :operatorPassword => :string,
    },
    :return => nil
  def balance
    render soap: nil
  end    
end
```

And some routing to that

```
# config/routes.rb 
wash_out :tains, 
    camelize_wsdl: true, 
    camelize_input: true,
    parser: :nokogiri, 
    wsdl_type: :rpc,
    namespace: 'http://services.integration.external.commons.tain.se/'

# bundle exec rake routes
WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.7.8, but has dynamically loaded 2.9.1
      Prefix Verb     URI Pattern   Controller#Action
  tains_wsdl GET      /tains/wsdl   tains#_generate_wsdl
tains_action GET|POST /tains/action #<WashOut::Router:0x007f92734a03c8 @controller_name="TainsController">
```

I've tried remove all configuration options and such but whatever I do I get the following error.

```
Started GET "/tains/wsdl" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-02 16:37:56 +0200
Processing by TainsController#_generate_wsdl as HTML
  Rendered /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/wash_out-0.8.3/app/views/wash_with_soap/rpc/wsdl.builder (2.9ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms

ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"_action", :controller=>"tains"}):
    49:
    50:   xml.service :name => "service" do
    51:     xml.port :name => "#{@name}_port", :binding => "tns:#{@name}_binding" do
    52:       xml.tag! "soap:address", :location => url_for(:action => '_action', :only_path => false)
    53:     end
    54:   end
    55:
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/journey/formatter.rb:39:in `generate'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:601:in `generate'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:631:in `generate'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:667:in `url_for'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb:155:in `url_for'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/action_view/routing_url_for.rb:83:in `url_for'
  wash_out (0.8.3) app/views/wash_with_soap/rpc/wsdl.builder:52:in `block (3 levels) in ___sers_mhenrixon__rbenv_versions_______p____lib_ruby_gems_______gems_wash_out_______app_views_wash_with_soap_rpc_wsdl_builder__2708187571820557370_70336765015180'
  builder (3.1.4) lib/builder/xmlbase.rb:170:in `call'
  builder (3.1.4) lib/builder/xmlbase.rb:170:in `_nested_structures'
  builder (3.1.4) lib/builder/xmlbase.rb:63:in `tag!'
  builder (3.1.4) lib/builder/xmlbase.rb:88:in `method_missing'
  wash_out (0.8.3) app/views/wash_with_soap/rpc/wsdl.builder:51:in `block (2 levels) in ___sers_mhenrixon__rbenv_versions_______p____lib_ruby_gems_______gems_wash_out_______app_views_wash_with_soap_rpc_wsdl_builder__2708187571820557370_70336765015180'
  builder (3.1.4) lib/builder/xmlbase.rb:170:in `call'
  builder (3.1.4) lib/builder/xmlbase.rb:170:in `_nested_structures'
  builder (3.1.4) lib/builder/xmlbase.rb:63:in `tag!'
  builder (3.1.4) lib/builder/xmlbase.rb:88:in `method_missing'
  wash_out (0.8.3) app/views/wash_with_soap/rpc/wsdl.builder:50:in `block in ___sers_mhenrixon__rbenv_versions_______p____lib_ruby_gems_______gems_wash_out_______app_views_wash_with_soap_rpc_wsdl_builder__2708187571820557370_70336765015180'
  builder (3.1.4) lib/builder/xmlbase.rb:170:in `call'
  builder (3.1.4) lib/builder/xmlbase.rb:170:in `_nested_structures'
  builder (3.1.4) lib/builder/xmlbase.rb:63:in `tag!'
  builder (3.1.4) lib/builder/xmlbase.rb:88:in `method_missing'
  wash_out (0.8.3) app/views/wash_with_soap/rpc/wsdl.builder:2:in `___sers_mhenrixon__rbenv_versions_______p____lib_ruby_gems_______gems_wash_out_______app_views_wash_with_soap_rpc_wsdl_builder__2708187571820557370_70336765015180'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `block in render'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/activesupport/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/activesupport/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/activesupport/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/action_view/template.rb:141:in `render'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:49:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/activesupport/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/activesupport/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/activesupport/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:48:in `block in render_template'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:56:in `render_with_layout'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `render_template'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:17:in `render'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:127:in `_render_template'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:219:in `_render_template'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:120:in `render_to_body'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:33:in `render_to_body'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:26:in `render_to_body'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:97:in `render'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/benchmark.rb:296:in `realtime'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
  wash_out (0.8.3) lib/wash_out/dispatcher.rb:92:in `_generate_wsdl'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:413:in `_run__1517166792173950683__process_action__callbacks'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/activesupport/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/activesupport/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/activesupport/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:680:in `call'
  bullet (4.6.0) lib/bullet/rack.rb:13:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.6.6.147) lib/new_relic/rack/error_collector.rb:43:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.6.6.147) lib/new_relic/rack/agent_hooks.rb:22:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.6.6.147) lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:16:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.6.6.147) lib/new_relic/rack/developer_mode.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/activerecord/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__2352099526304846558__call__callbacks'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/railties/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/railties/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/activesupport/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/activesupport/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/activesupport/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/railties/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/activesupport/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack-cors (0.2.8) lib/rack/cors.rb:54:in `call'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/railties/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/railties/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/deflater.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  puma (2.5.1) lib/puma/server.rb:472:in `handle_request'
  puma (2.5.1) lib/puma/server.rb:343:in `process_client'
  puma (2.5.1) lib/puma/server.rb:242:in `block in run'
  puma (2.5.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:92:in `call'
  puma (2.5.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:92:in `block in spawn_thread'


  Rendered /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/mhenrixon/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rails-4c92851f1645/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.erb within rescues/layout (9.2ms)
```

Anyone know why that might happen? Looks to me like wash_out isn't working properly.

Comment: Pleas add an output of `rake routes` to the question.

Comment: as requested it is now done

Comment: routes get generated properly. And I can't reproduce it on Rails 4. Are you sure you get same error when you get rid of those additional routing params? Cause they are not allowed that's for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be incostitency (or maybe a bug) introduced to `4.0.1` branch of Rails. Fixed with a workaround: https://github.com/inossidabile/wash_out/issues/108.